# llenar formulario web desde la consola

Tags: javascript, web, formularios

Tengo un formulario web que lo tengo que rellenar desde la consola de "Chrome". En los casilleros de texto no tengo problemas. Uso por ejemplo:

```
txtNombre.value='nombre';
```

pero tengo un problema con casilleros tipo select que se son dependientes entre si es decir el primer desplagable activa un segundo y asi hasta un total de 3

el primer desplegable logro llenar segun los valores pero no activa el segundo desplegable para ser llenado como si no reconociera los datos ingresados en el primer campo o si faltara algun tipo de refresh

soy nuevo en este tema cualquier cosa me puedan ayudar

**primer desplegable**

```
<select name="aviso.idProvincia" id="aviso.idProvincia" class="geo-select  cepProvincia valid" data-action="obtenerCiudades" data-combo="aviso.idCiudad" data-combo-reset="aviso.idZona">
<option value="">Elegir una provincia</option>
<option value="1200">Bocas del Toro</option>
<option value="1210">Chiriquí</option>
<option value="1220">Coclé</option>
<option value="394">Colón</option>
<option value="1500">Darién</option>
<option value="1320">Emberá</option>
<option value="395">Herrera</option>
<option value="1310">Kuna Yala</option>
<option value="1240">Los Santos</option>
<option value="1300">Ngöbe Buglé</option>
<option value="396">Panamá</option>
<option value="1501">Panamá Oeste</option>
<option value="1260">Veraguas</option>
</select>
```

**segundo despllegable sin estar activo**

```
<select name="aviso.idCiudad" id="aviso.idCiudad" data-action="obtenerZonas" data-combo="aviso.idZona" disabled="" class="geo-select-2  cepCiudad">
<option value="">Elegir una distrito</option>
</select>
```

**segundo desplegable ya con una opcion del primero seleccionada esto es lo que no logro generar con el llenado desde la consola**

```
<select name="aviso.idCiudad" id="aviso.idCiudad" data-action="obtenerZonas" data-combo="aviso.idZona" class="geo-select-2  cepCiudad">

<li class="holder"><span>No hay barrios cercanos</span></li>
<option value="">Elegir una distrito
</option><option value="3039">Bocas del Toro
</option><option value="3120">Cauchero
</option><option value="3038">Changuinola
</option><option value="3037">Chiriquí Grande
</option></select>
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que queres hacer, como que dependen entre si? a que te referis con que el primero "activa" un segundo? que hay que clickearlo?, lo que estas haciendo con txtNombre.value='nombre' es cambiar el valor de algo que ya existe. El segundo select esta vacio, no podrias agregar <options> a no ser que uses Javascript

Comment: Lo que yo entendí es que abre una página web con un formulario y a través de la consola de chrome lo llena, supongo que lo que estás haciendo es como un "script" para llenar el formulario desde la consola de chrome?

Comment: Correcto, cuando digo que son dependientes es que al seleccionar algo del primero se activan el segundo desplegable según la selección que hice y si lo que estoy haciendo es un script de llenado de formulario desde la consola de chrome

Comment: Pero ya encontré la solución